# Rails static model with multiple columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was reading into using `enums` for some static models in rails, things like statuses can be a good candidate for a simple usage.

```
enum status: {active: 0, archived: 1}
```

I get the above, then I try to expand a little. I now have a static model which I would like to have more columns, I am not too sure how to implement this.

Let's say I have a status static model, but I want to tie in more properties to each of the status. E.g.:

```
active: {value: 0, rank: 3, description: "Activated"}
archived: {value: 1, rank: 2, description: "Archived"}
deleted: {value: 2, rank: 1, description: "Removed"}
```

All the data are still static and will not change, but then there is a property binded.. How can I use the static model design pattern to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

Its better to have a properties as a single column with **text** datatype where you can store your contents as a serialized hash. For eg if I am having a book model with some attributes to book with different editions means then design for the properties column will be like

```
           :edition1: 
             noofpages: 400
             price: 420$
             isbn: ksn78n
```

Comment: don't follow you here.

Answer (score 0):

The [ActiveHash Gem](https://github.com/zilkey/active_hash) allows doing this:

> ActiveHash is a simple base class that allows you to use a ruby hash as a readonly datasource for an ActiveRecord-like model.
>   ActiveHash assumes that every hash has an :id key, which is what you would probably store in a database. This allows you to seamlessly upgrade from ActiveHash objects to full ActiveRecord objects without having to change any code in your app, or any foreign keys in your database.